# Count number of observations by group in past week using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an unbalanced panel where an individual is observed repeatedly at irregular intervals. I want to calculate how many times each individual in the panel was observed in the past week using pandas.

```
Id     Date
 a   2000-01-01
 a   2000-01-02
 a   2000-01-05
 b   2000-01-01
 b   2000-02-01
```

Becomes

```
Id     Date       Count
 a   2000-01-01     0
 a   2000-01-02     1
 a   2000-01-05     2
 b   2000-01-01     0
 b   2000-02-01     0
```

Resampling approach doesn't seem to work because I can't resample when indexed by Id and Date...

Comment: You'll get more people playing with your data if you post it in a form we can copy-paste-run as a dataframe. `df.to_dict()` will produce a string format, for instance.

Comment: Why is the count 0 for Id b on 2000-02-01?  
Ahhh....  "IN THE PAST WEEK"
In which case, the past week relative to when?
BTW, are you using yyyy-dd-mm or yyyy-mm-dd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it wasn't working when I tried `pd.rolling_count`, so I put this together. Not sure if it is the most efficient but it works.

```
def count_obs(df, interval=7):
    idx = df['Date']
    df['temp'] = 1
    by_day = df.set_index('Date').resample('D').fillna(0)
    csum = by_day['temp'].cumsum()
    by_day['Count'] = csum - csum.shift(interval).fillna(0)
    return by_day.ix[by_day.index.isin(idx), 'Count']

df.groupby('Id').apply(count_obs)
```